# Passing half of a text file to one node of a linked list and the second part to another using C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created a linked list of just two nodes in the following way for testing purposes:

```
void implement (int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (new == NULL)
        {
            printf("Out of memory!\n");
            return;
        }

        new->i = i;
        new->link = head;
        head = new; 
    }
}
```

where size is 2 for now and the node is of the following type:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int i; 
    char array[100];
    struct node* link;
}node; 

node* head = NULL;
```

My aim is from the following text file:

```
A, B
```

to pass A, to one node and then B to the other, using the following code:

```
char* data;
data = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);


fgets(data, 30, inptr);

node* cur = head;
int n = 0; 

for (int i = 0, j = 6; i < j; i++)
{

   cur->array[n] = data[i];
   n++;
   printf("%s", cur->array); 

   if(data[i] == ',')
   {

        cur = cur->link;

   }


}

for (node* ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->link)
{
    printf("%s\n", ptr->array); 
}
```

However, my output is the following for the first printf statement:

AA,

and then for the second printf statement iterating through the linked list, nothing. I have been through the program using gdb and it seems to work fine, so I cannot see quite what the problem is here. Any advice/tips would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I should say, if I change data to be: char data[100], I then obtain "A," for the second printf statement ie this is now being observed in the first node. However, the second node appears to remain blank despite gdb suggesting that 'B' was passed to this second node...

Comment: You are missing n=0 after cur = cur->link;

Comment: Eyes of a hawk my friend...  that's the ticket. Can you explain why this does not work if data is dynamically allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing n=0 after cur = cur->link;